# Is there a project/library for building Kendo chart run-time editor?

Tags: kendo-ui, data-visualization, kendo-chart

I'm sorry if my title isn't clear but I wasn't quite sure how to phrase this question in that small space.  What I'm wanting to do is provide users the ability to build data visualizations within my web app using the Telerik Kendo Chart controls.  I'm not trying to build anything as sophisticated at Power BI but that is the idea.  I want to provide them a list of visualization controls and a set of fields to be able to build visualizations in real-time.

I'm willing to build this functionality but I thought surely someone else has already done this and would love to not have to do this from scratch.  Does anyone know of any existing projects or libraries that do this currently using the Kendo UI controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar project an after some search I decide to create my on interface and render the charts in a more dynamic way.

Basically what I did was load a chart with sample random data and a form for the user to change the type of chart, data, titles, scale etc...

Here is an example on how to apply the user changes like this:

```
var chart = $("#kendoChartResult").data("kendoChart");        
var datasourceData = JSON.parse($("#seriesValues").val().replace(/\n/g, ''));
    
    chart.setOptions({
        title: { text: $("#chartTitle").val() },
        chartArea: { width: $("#chartWidth").val(), height: $("#chartHeight").val() },
        categoryAxis: { title: { text: $("#categoryAxisTitle").val() } },
        
        valueAxis: {
            title: {
                text: $("#valuesTitle").val()
            },
            min: parseInt($("#minValue").val()),
            max: parseInt($("#maxValue").val()),
            axisCrossingValue: parseInt($("#axisCrossingValue").val()),                
            labels: {
                format: $("#valueAxisFormat").val().replace(/ /, '')
            },
            reverse: reverse
        },
        dataSource: {
            data: datasourceData
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            type: $("#chartType").val()
        }
```

Obviously there are some variables that pick value from the form user imputs to recreate the chart dynamicaly